# Visual Studio 2019: Stop debugger when browser window is closed but do NOT close browser when debugging stops

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

[image]

If I close a browser running a web application, it is desirable that the debugging session dies. After all, this equals to closing a windows application. However, if I stop debugging and the browser has more than one tabs (as often is the case), all of them will close - definitely not what I intended. Not using this option means I continuously forget the debugger running and clicking the stop button is just extra work.

Is there an add-on to Visual Studio or any other trick that allows to do only the first: stop debugger when window is closed?

Who thought it would be a good idea to put two options behind a single checkbox? This is a double-edged sword at its sharpest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want. But, it might be a workaround. If you enable JavaScript debugging in Tools->Options->Debugging and then you Debug->Detach All. The browser should stay open and debugging should stop... Now it would mean that the application is still running, which might not be desirable.

It's a great suggestion to make this an option. I'd encourage you to open a suggestion on [developer community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=8).

Tools Options:

[image: Tools Options]

Detach:

[image: Debug Menu]